# Merge multiple sublists where the value is not zero

Tags: python

What is the best way in Python to perform a merge where the value is not 0, resulting in the following outcome?

```
list = [
    [0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 'b', 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'c', 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '']
]

[[0, 0, 0, '', 'b', 0, 'c', '', '']] # result
```

Comment: _where the value is not 0_ I see plenty of zeroes in your result... Please explain exactly what you mean by "merge where the value is not 0".  Also please show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: What if one column has two non-zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter 0s from the sublists transposed with `zip`:

```
[next((i for i in s if i != 0), 0) for s in zip(*lst)]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/brrPH3

Comment: Or just `map(max, zip(*lst))` :-) https://ideone.com/VWXHsB

Comment: Interesting code golfing, I did not know that a string is considered greater than a number in Python 2. But then even in Python 2 the code would fail to produce the right result when the input contains a negative number.

Comment: It's because `'str' > 'int'`. Oh, the good old times.

Comment: Ah hahaha, whoever came up with such a default behavior for comparisons must've been high at the time.